# Angular Material Toast Within a Specific Element

Tags: angularjs, position, element, angular-material, toast

I want to know whether is there any easy way to display angular material toast within a specific element.

I'm using Angular-Material Version 1.0.5

Answer (score 5):

**HTML**

```
<div id="toastContainer">
</div>
```

**Angular-Material Toast Code**

```
$mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple({
        textContent : "Raise your glass in a toast to myself ;-)",
        parent : $document[0].querySelector('#toastContainer'),
        hideDelay: 6000
    })
    );
```

Comment: Just to complement Nimantha's answer: I managed to use it just passing a string with the element id, like this: `.parent('#patient-detail-card')`